# How to Hide the Document Preview

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

[image]

Someone knows how i can hide the bar that is in red?

It appeared after the 1.13 update....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"editor.minimap.enabled": false
```

Solved the problem.